# Show VBA userform with variables in userform name

Tags: vba, powerpoint, userform

I am doing a PPT where I need to click buttons to show various Forms.

I have created a public function in the main module.

```
Public Function ShowForm(FormName As String)
    Dim oneForm As Object
    For Each oneForm In UserForms
        If oneForm.Name = FormName Then
            oneForm.Show
            End
        End If
    Next oneForm
End Function
```

And used it in the button below:

```
Private Sub NextPage_Click()

ShowForm ("SU0" & qlist(cntr))
cntr = cntr + 1

End Sub
```

But the function does not work. Did I miss anything or is there a better way of doing this?

---

## Solved

Google is the key...

I have changed the function in the module and everything works fine now.

```
Public Function ShowForm(FormName As String)
    Dim oneForm As Object
    Set oneForm = CallByName(UserForms, "Add", VbMethod, FormName)
    oneForm.Show
End Function
```

Note that in order to handle multiple userforms, the "ShowModal" property of those forms needs to be set to FALSE.

Comment: When you say 'does not work', do you mean nothing happens or is there an error, etc.?

Comment: I'm assuming `qlist(cntr)`is your variable, when and where is it defined/set in your code?

Comment: There is no error shown up. It simply does not do anything when I click the button. yes, qlist is an array of integers which is declared in the module as a public variant. qlist is created when the first form is active and it will be used for the rest of the application. cntr is also a public integer which accumulated every time a button is clicked.

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Comment: Why did you use `CallByName(UserForms, "Add", VbMethod, FormName)`? That would simply be `UserForms.Add(FormName)`.