# How to run a macro with another macro/Function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, macros, user-defined-functions

I want to call a Object/Sub-routine/userform  with VBA UDF/Macro in Excel VBA. I am giving an example.

**Example Scenario:** I have 03 command button for to change font case based on A1 and B1 cell value. Here with image 01, my purpose is solved. Here, I write similar pattern code for 03 times. So, now I am curious to write this code for one time with  a user defined function and then recall it like as Image 02.

Please note, I know may be this can be solved with If...Elseif statement like Image 03. But I don't want to get the solution with this approach because I have lots of macro and i want to call then with a simple function like Image 02.

[image: Image 01]
[image: Image 02]
[image: Image 03]

Comment: Do not place the pictures of your code, please! Ever! Please, edit your question and paste the code as it is. And it is a matter of a UDF function, I am afraid that it is able to return only in the cell where has been called from. If you better explain what you want accomplishing, we will show you another way to do that...

Comment: We maybe need to test your code and nobody like writing code looking to a picture.

Comment: I have tried to copy paste the code there. But I don't know, code line is broken and looks like messy. That's they I have shared the Google drive like for All code.. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: @mohsin May be a good time to do what you should have done at the beginning, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and observe the [formatting rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: In order to make the code to look as it is in your module, you should put it between ``` your code ``` characters. The character before the 1 key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
private sub commandbutton1_click()
  CommonMacro "Sheet1.UcaseFont"
end sub

private sub commandbutton2_click()
  CommonMacro "Sheet1.LcaseFont"
end sub

private sub commandbutton3_click()
  CommonMacro "Sheet1.ProperCaseFont"
end sub

Function CommonMacro(byval MacroRun as string)
  ...
  Application.Run MacroRun
  ...
end function
```

Comment: @mohsin It is working for me, and it is going to work for you given the code you have shown. If it doesn't work, please explain how it doesn't work.

Comment: Wow... Yes yes... this is working for me.... <br/>

Many Thanks for your help. Just curios to know more 02 things
1. If i dont want to mention Sheet1 name... Then what will be code. 

private sub commandbutton1_click()

  CommonMacro "UcaseFont"

end sub


2. If I want to link with cell value as below, then it is not working. Can you please advise how can I solve this?

 Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim x As String

    x = Range("C1").Value

    CommonMacro " & x & "

End Sub

Comment: @mohsin If you don't want to mention `Sheet1`, then move the `UcaseFont` etc macros out of a sheet module into a standard module. For 2, `CommonMacro x`.

Comment: Absolute working... In case any UserForm show instead of call MacroRun then what will be code instead of Application.Run MacroRun?

Comment: @mohsin It would be `Application.Run MacroRun`, and then inside the macro you show the userform.

Comment: I got it... But is there any direct way to call a userform to show with UDF by setting MacroRun as Object as below?

Function CommonMacro(byval MacroRun as Object)
  ...
  MacroRun.Show
  ...
end function

Comment: @mohsin `Function CommonMacro(byval MacroRun as UserForm)`, `CommonMacro New UserForm1`?

Comment: actually for every userform, I need to write CommonMacro New UserForm1 or any other userform name. Rather then doing this I need more dynamic approach like your above sub-routine solution.... CommonMacro "AnyUserformName"

Comment: @mohsin https://stackoverflow.com/q/51397325/11683?